# Select rows having duplicates from a table in mysql (rows contain null values)

Tags: mysql

This is my table

```
+-------+--------+--------+--------+----+
| name  | value1 | value2 | value3 | id |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+----+
| Alice | p      | y      | r      | 1  |
| Ted   | g      | b      | t      | 10 |
| Bob   | g      | NULL   | x      | 2  |
| Jack  | NULL   | NULL   | x      | 3  |
| Joe   | g      | NULL   | x      | 4  |
| John  | g      | NULL   | x      | 5  |
| Maria | a      | b      | c      | 6  |
| Mark  | g      | b      | t      | 7  |
| Mary  | t      | j      | NULL   | 8  |
| Sam   | NULL   | NULL   | x      | 9  |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+----+
```

I want to select rows that have duplicate values. I used this query:

```
    SELECT * from my_table 
WHERE (value1, value2, value3) IN 
(SELECT value1, value2, value3 
   FROM my_table 
   GROUP BY value1, value2, value3 
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) 
ORDER BY value1, value2, value3;
```

The result of my query is this:

```
+------+--------+--------+--------+----+
| name | value1 | value2 | value3 | id |
+------+--------+--------+--------+----+
| Ted  | g      | b      | t      | 10 |
| Mark | g      | b      | t      | 7  |
+------+--------+--------+--------+----+
```

It does not select rows with null values because comparing two null values results in a null. But I want rows with null values to be included in my result. 
How do I write a query for it?

Answer (score 0):

I was not going to post an answer because my solution is not great.  But since you have zero other answers thought I would try to help.  If your table is not very large, you can create another table Setting NULL columns=Any other value not present in your table.

```
SELECT value1,IF(value1 IS NULL, '1',value1) AS value_convert FROM `table` GROUP BY 
value1;
```

Then run your query on this table.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I actually replace null values with empty string and did it.